# create a grid array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to setup a grid containing **m * n** objects. This grid got a width of **m** rows and **n** columns.

I tried this code first

```
let map = [][]; // Create an array that takes a x and y index

function createMap() {
    for (let x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
            addCell(x, y); 
        }
    }
}

function addCell(x, y) {
    map[x][y] = cell(); // create a new object on x and y
}
```

Obviously this is a wrong syntax. The initialization of map is wrong. How can I create the array that I can access a object by passing in the x and y coordinate to the array?

Let's say I want to access the object on (3|7) I want to go for `map[3][7]`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

You cant initialize a 2d array, as there are no real 2d arrays in js. However you could setup a regular array, and add arrays to it:

```
 function createMap(columnCount, rowCount) {
   const map = [];
   for (let x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
     map[x] = []; // set up inner array
     for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
        addCell(map, x, y);
     }
   }
   return map;
 }

 function addCell(map, x, y) {
    map[x][y] = cell(); // create a new object on x and y
 }

 const map = createMap(10, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a single array as value and a check if one row does not exist.

```js
function createMap(rowCount, columnCount) {
    for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < columnCount; y++) {
            addCell(x, y); 
        }
    }
}

function addCell(x, y) {
    map[x] = map[x] || [];
    map[x][y] = x + '|' + y;
}

var map = [];
createMap(4, 8);

console.log(map[3][7]);
console.log(map);
```

An approach by using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
function createMap(rowCount, columnCount) {
    map = Array.from(
        { length: rowCount },           // take rowCount as length
        (_, i) => Array.from(           // fill with new array
            { length: columnCount },    // take columnCount for every row
            (_, j) => [i, j].join('|')  // initialize cell with some value
        )
    );
}

var map;
createMap(4, 8);

console.log(map[3][7]);
console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually that far off with your solution. You're right, though, you cannot initialize a two-dimensional array like `let a = [][]`. If you add just one line to your for-loops, your solution also produces a map-like structure:

In your `createMap()` function, you just need to initialize every field of the the array with an array, after that you can fill the fields of this array:

```
function createMap() {
    for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        map[x] = []; // initialize map[x] as an array
        for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            addCell(x, y); 
        }
    }
}
```

And initialize `map`  as a simple array.

Here is a working example:

```js
let map = [];

createMap();

console.log(map);

function createMap() {
    for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        map[x] = [];
        for (let y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            addCell(x, y); 
        }
    }
}

function addCell(x, y) {
    map[x][y] = cell(x,y); // create a new object on x and y
}

function cell(x,y) {
 return (x+1)+":"+(y+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are having trouble creating the grid or displaying it.

Here is yet another way to create it:

```
const grid = Array.from(new Array(5),(_,x)=>Array.from(new Array(5),(_,y)=>addCell(x,y)));
```

Here are 2 ways to show the grid:

```js
const grid = Array.from(new Array(5),()=>Array.from(new Array(5),()=>"-"));

const rotate = grid => 
  grid[0].map(
    (_,y)=>grid.map(
      (_,x)=>[y,x]
    )
  ).map(
    row=>row.map(([x,y])=>grid[y][x])
  );
const format = grid => grid.map(x=>x.join(" ")).join("\n");
//set some values of grid
[[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2]].forEach(
  ([x,y])=>grid[x][y]="X"
);

//you can map the grid to columns first, it'll look like it's rotated
//  unless you generate the columns in div float lefts
console.log("map grid columns first:")
console.log(format(grid));

//you can rotate the grid to build each row and then each column like html table
console.log("map grid rows first:")
console.log(format(rotate(grid)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var grid=[];
var grid_length=10; //mathematical length
var grid_width=10;  //mathematical width

function pos(x,y){
  return (y*grid_length)-grid_length-1+x-2;
}

function replaceItem(x,y,item){
  grid[pos(x,y)]=item;
}

var itemsRequested=[];
function iRequest(x,y){ // get Item on grid.
  itemsRequested.push(grid[pos(x,y)]);  // this both adds the Object to a list and returns it
  return grid[pos(x,y)];
}
```

This method only makes a mathematical grid, with which you can reference with the `pos()` function.

Then to answer your question to get the object on 3,7 you would simply say

```
var a=iRequest(3,7);
//currently would return undefined because there are no objects in the array.
```

When using this method, 1,1 is the top left corner, and `pos(1,1)` would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional method that doesn't rely on any reassignment or mutation:

```js
const lengthX = 5;
const lengthY = 2;
const map = Array.from({ length: lengthX }, (_, colIndex) => (
  Array.from({ length: lengthY }, (_, rowIndex) => (
    // some element to put in each, for example
    { foo: 'bar'}
  ))
));
console.log(map);
```

The `colIndex` and `rowIndex` are optional, they're not used in this snippet, but if you need to create elements based on their location in the grid, they're the variables to use.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var x = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   x[i] = new Array(20);
}
x[5][12] = 3.0;
```